# Javascript parseInt - Code running 4 times

Tags: javascript, parseint

For this function, I am trying to calculate the outcome of the $r variables and display them in a form input text field, "otherHtmlIdName".

The if statement checks to see if they all have values, then gets the calculated variable's value and changes the input field. It works great, the problem is that it works 4 times in a row, once for every `parseInt()`.

Is there any way I can just make it run once? I've tried `parseFloat` and `Number` as well. Didn't help.

[Edit]: This wasn't happening because of parseInt. I was calling the click function on this ID 4 times in my code.

```
$("#htmlIdName").click(function () {
    var variableName = parseInt($r.ab3, 10) - parseInt($r.ab4, 10) + parseInt($r.sb3, 10) + parseInt($r.sb4, 10);
    if ($r.ab3 && $r.ab4 && $r.sb3 && $r.sb4) {
        $("#otherHtmlIdName").val(variableName);
        $("#otherHtmlIdName").change();
    };
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean that it "works" once for every `parseInt()` call? How can you tell? That doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You say that the click handler runs 4 times, or that you have to call parseInt 4 times ?

Comment: If it's the latter, you don't really have a choice since the numbers you are parsing are different (ab3, ab4, sb3, sb4). You have to call parseInt 4 times.

Comment: Also, if one of your parsed variables is not a number string, your resulting `variableName` will be `NaN`. You might want to check that before setting your `#otherHtmlIdName` to the string "NaN".

Comment: I set break points in the code and watched it with Firebug. It went through the whole function 4 times. I'm guessing that it was caused by the 4 different values with parseInt() because I have already ruled out that it wasn't caused by the "if" check.

Comment: Check that 1) you only clicked 1 time :-) 2) the above `.click` handler is not set multiple times in your code and 3) the `#htmlIdName` is not given to 4 different elements in your html (it would be invalid html otherwise anyway).

Comment: kliron, You might have something there. It's the name of a button tab that takes you to the subview that displays the input I'm adding the calculations to. It is called elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#htmlIdName").off().on('click', function() {
    /* Your code here */
});
```

Comment: I can't tell if this works or not. Since #htmlIdName is a button that brings you to the page that shows the input I'm looking for, this turns off the button.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because you actually answered my question in a comment above. I have the $("#htmlIdName").click being called 4 times in my code. I need to find something else to attach this to.

Comment: @H311B0Y What `off()` does is remove any registered handlers before attaching the 'click' handler above. It would work but it would probably be better if you find out why the handler is registered multiple times and correct your code if this is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to prevent calling `parseInt()` 4 times, you could use the `map` function like this:

```
$("#htmlIdName").click(function() {
  //convert object of strings to array of ints
  var arr = $.map($r, function(el) {
    return +el
  });

  //perform same calculations as before
  var variableName = arr[0] - arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];

  if ($r.ab3 && $r.ab4 && $r.sb3 && $r.sb4) {
    $("#otherHtmlIdName").val(variableName);
    $("#otherHtmlIdName").change();
  };
});
```

Working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZExeM

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b, but I'm not sure I understand how this works. I have several dozen jquery calls to input field IDs preceding in the code that are set up like the $("#otherHtmlIdName") ones, and I changed a few of them to make an $r variable so I can calculate this arithmetic. Can I group them in a different way than taking the ID names and putting them in a $r variable? Why does this calculate integers instead of concatonating strings like it was before?

Comment: ``map`` applies the function you pass it to every element in the object/array. all this function is doing is returning each element after applying the unary + to it, which automatically parses it to an int (as long as the string is already in an integer form). The reason it did not work with your codeis that you are using a binary +, which doesn't apply the conversion. 

you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()